# Inserting carriage returns when sending text to the iOS Calendar

Tags: ios, string, swift, calendar, multiline

I'm sending text to the iOS calendar using the following code.

```
event.title = " \(jobTitle) \r\n" + "\(jobDescription)"
```

This does not work. I don't get a carriage return. Does anybody know of a work around to get my job titles and job descriptions to display on a multiline when sending to event.title?

Comment: Well normaly the "\n" is the typical expression for that... could you try to delete the "\r", or have you tried this?

Comment: If what you tried doesn't work, then I doubt this is possible :(

Comment: Yes Neo, I've tried that. It doesn't look like Swift supports multiline. I've searched but just wondered if the community knew of some sort of workaround. Right now I can place the job description into the calendar notes but I thought it would look better if I could display the description underneath the job title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
event.title = "\(jobTitle)\n\(jobDescription)"
```

should works.

Note: **not** every view in iOS Calendar application correctly display multi-line title event.

For example:

```
ev.title = "TestJobTitle\nTest job description"
```

List view:
[image: screenshot3]
Detail view:
[image: screenshot1]
Grid view:
[image: screenshot2]